# PHP array_slice method to output only desired array

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have an array say :

```
$input = Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [message] => 1 file(s) do not conform to the xxx naming standards.
            [type] => warning
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Package
                            [property] => zip
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Name
                            [property] => name
                        )

                )

            [rows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [zip] => abcd.zip
                        )

                )

        )

    [111] => Array
        (
            [message] => Invalid it is
            [type] => error
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ID
                            [property] => id
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Title
                            [property] => title
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Zip
                            [property] => zip
                        )

                )

            [rows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => abcd
                            [title] => title
                            [zip] => abcd
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Then I calculate length as below : 
 $length = count($this->view->feedback);
 $i= 0;

Now I am running a foreach loop as

```
foreach ($input as $operation)
{
    if($operation['type'] == 'error')
    {
        $output = array_slice($operation, -$i, $length);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

The above array_slice() method outputs as below :

```
$output = 
 Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 214501
                    [title] => SRM- 3860(Res-2)
                    [zip] => SRM-3860(Test_2).zip
                )

        )

)
```

My DESIRED/REQUIRED output is :

```
$output = 
Array
(
    [111] => Array
        (
            [message] => Invalid it is
            [type] => error
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ID
                            [property] => id
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Title
                            [property] => title
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Zip
                            [property] => zip
                        )

                )

            [rows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => abcd
                            [title] => title
                            [zip] => abcd
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

How can I achieve this ?
Is something wrong with my array_slice method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
$my_desired_output = [];
foreach ($input as $key => $operation)
{
    if($operation['type'] == 'error')
    {
        $my_desired_output[$key] = $operation;
    }
}
```